# In GXT 3 how to access another field in same row during handling of onCompleteEdit event

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt, inline-editing

I have a GridInlineEditing object for GXT 3.0 grid.  It all works as expected - I can capture user editing events and find out the row, column and model/change-record for this event.

What I have not figured out is how to best access another control in that row.

Specifically, I have this Column model:

```
    private void initializeColumnModel() {

    // Create the configurations for each column in the grid
    List<ColumnConfig<Reminder, ?>> ccs = new LinkedList<ColumnConfig<Reminder, ?>>();
    typeColumnConfig        = new ColumnConfig<Reminder,String>(    properties.name(),          120,    "Type"      );
    completedColumnConfig   = getDateCellColumn(                    properties.completed_(),    200,    "Completed" ); 
    dueColumnConfig         = getDateCellColumn(                    properties.due_(),          200,    "Due"       ); 
    applicableColumnConfig  = new ColumnConfig<Reminder,Boolean>(   properties.applicable(),    140,    "Applicable");

    // Add column configurations to ColumnModel.
    ccs.add(typeColumnConfig);
    ccs.add(completedColumnConfig);
    ccs.add(dueColumnConfig);
    ccs.add(applicableColumnConfig);
    applicableColumnConfig.setAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    typeColumnConfig.setAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    reminderColumnModel = new ColumnModel<Reminder>(ccs);
}
```

and am attempting to intercept a change to the 'completed date' value and then programmatically operate the 'due date' control (adding a fixed number of years to that as if the user just did it).

Here's how I capture the event:

```
    @Override
public Widget asWidget() {
    if(!gridInitialized){
        editing = new GridInlineEditing<Reminder>(grid);

        DateField dueDateField          = getDateField();
        DateField completedDateField    = getDateField();

        editing.addEditor(dueColumnConfig,          dueDateField);
        editing.addEditor(completedColumnConfig,    completedDateField);
        editing.addEditor(applicableColumnConfig,   new CheckBox());

        editing.addCompleteEditHandler(new CompleteEditHandler<Reminder>(){
            @Override
            public void onCompleteEdit(CompleteEditEvent<Reminder> event) {
                GridCell cell = event.getEditCell();
                int row = cell.getRow();
                int col = cell.getCol();
                Reminder rem = reminderStore.get(row);
                Store<Reminder>.Record rec = reminderStore.getRecord(rem);
                //System.out.println("row:"+row+", col:"+col+", applic:"+rem.getApplicable());
                //System.out.println("rec:"+rec.toString());
                Change<Reminder, Boolean> applicChange  = rec.getChange(properties.applicable());
                Change<Reminder, Date>      dueChange   = rec.getChange(properties.due_());
                Change<Reminder, Date>      comChange   = rec.getChange(properties.completed_());
                System.err.print("Row "+(row+1)+" changed: ");
                if(applicChange!=null){
                    boolean applicValue = applicChange.getValue();
                    System.out.println("applicable changed to "+applicValue);
                }
                if(dueChange!=null){
                    Date dueValue = dueChange.getValue();
                    System.out.println("due changed to: "+SimpleDate.convertFromDate(dueValue));
                }
                if(comChange!=null){
                    Date comValue = comChange.getValue();
                    System.out.println("com changed to: "+SimpleDate.convertFromDate(comValue));
                    try{
                        fixDueDate(row,comValue, rem);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        //boo.
                        System.err.println("Could not update the due date for this completion date change.");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        gridInitialized=true;
    }
    // Initialize the Revert Changes button.
    revert.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            reminderStore.rejectChanges();
        }
    });

    return widget;
}
```

The method 'fixDueDate' is where I hope to place my logic that adjusts the other column control (another DateField):

```
    private void fixDueDate(int row, Date completedDate, Reminder rem) throws InvalidDateFormatException, InvalidDateException{
    SimpleDate newCompDate = new SimpleDate(completedDate);
    SimpleDate dueDate = newCompDate.addYears(rem.getRenewalYears());


    //rem.setDue(dueDate.getFormattedDate());
    //reminderStore.update(rem);
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    private void fixDueDate(int row, Date completedDate, Reminder rem, Store<Reminder>.Record rec ) 
        throws InvalidDateFormatException, InvalidDateException{
    SimpleDate newCompDate = new SimpleDate(completedDate);
    SimpleDate dueDate = newCompDate.addYears(rem.getRenewalYears());

    rec.addChange(dueColumnConfig.getValueProvider(), dueDate.toDate());

}
```

and the modified field marks appear on both the user modified field and the field modified by this rec.addChange call above.